# How to extract capitalized parts from a text?

Tags: php, regex, string

Which php function can be used to extract capitalized words from a string?

For example, I have:

`... a large text that contains CAPITALIZED PARTS ...`

and I need to programmatically extract `CAPITALIZED PARTS` from it.

I have searched the internet, but have not found any solution.

Comment: use reguler expression

Comment: @Testing, my question is indeed a duplicate. I searched stack overflow before asking this, how come I missed that question.

Comment: No problem. :) they all have given you the similar answers the one same like answered in that question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `\\b[A-Z]+\\b` regex to get ALLCAPS words with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php):

Here is a [sample program](http://goo.gl/MXw9kU):

```
<?php
 $re = "/\\b[A-Z]+\\b/"; 
 $str = "a large text that contains CAPITALIZED PARTS"; 
 preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
 foreach ($matches as $val) {
     print_r($val);
 }
?>
```

Output:

```
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [0] => CAPITALIZED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    [1] => PARTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
)
```

Comment: OP requested only `CAPITALIZED PARTS` not starting with `CAPITAL AND SMALL`. You should consider posting some `demo link`.

Comment: I see, the post has been updated. "Capitalized" is not the same as ALLCAPS words.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Consider update your answer please as its seems the good answer to me.

Comment: @Testing: I updated the answer now. However, I am not sure you want the separate words, or whole chunks of ALLCAPS words? If you need to return word chunks, you should also allow (white)space in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regex which is case sensitive by default

```
$string='... a large text that contains CAPITALIZED PARTS ...'
preg_match_all('%[A-Z]+%', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

https://regex101.com/r/eB0rH5/1

Answer (score 0):

```
$re = "/[A-Z]*/"; 
$str = "a large text that contains CAPITALIZED PARTS"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);


$newArr = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $mat){
    if(strlen($mat)>0)
    $newArr[] = $mat; 
}
print_r($newArr);
```